# Convert java.util.HashMap to scala.collection.immutable.Map in java

Tags: java, scala, scala-collections

I'm using some Scala library from my Java code. And I have a problem with collections. I need to pass `scala.collection.immutable.Map` as a parameter of a method. I can convert or build `immutable.Map` from my Java code but I do not know how to do it. Suggestions?

Answer (score 24):

It's entirely possible to use `JavaConverters` in Java code—there are just a couple of additional hoops to jump through:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import scala.Predef;
import scala.Tuple2;
import scala.collection.JavaConverters;
import scala.collection.immutable.Map;

public class ToScalaExample {
  public static <A, B> Map<A, B> toScalaMap(HashMap<A, B> m) {
    return JavaConverters.mapAsScalaMapConverter(m).asScala().toMap(
      Predef.<Tuple2<A, B>>conforms()
    );
  }

  public static HashMap<String, String> example() {
    HashMap<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
    m.put("a", "A");
    m.put("b", "B");
    m.put("c", "C");
    return m;
  }
}
```

We can show that this works from the Scala REPL:

```
scala> val jm: java.util.HashMap[String, String] = ToScalaExample.example
jm: java.util.HashMap[String,String] = {b=B, c=C, a=A}

scala> val sm: Map[String, String] = ToScalaExample.toScalaMap(jm)
sm: Map[String,String] = Map(b -> B, c -> C, a -> A)
```

But of course you could just as easily call these methods from Java code.

Comment: There is no "toMap" method any more. The code above can't be compiled for Java 1.7 and Scala 2.11 :(

Comment: jdk 1.8, it shows "can't access scala.Predef.$less$colon$less" error

Answer (score 5):

My solution for Java 1.7 and Scala 2.11:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <K, V> scala.collection.immutable.Map<K, V> toScalaImmutableMap(java.util.Map<K, V> javaMap) {
    final java.util.List<scala.Tuple2<K, V>> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>(javaMap.size());
    for (final java.util.Map.Entry<K, V> entry : javaMap.entrySet()) {
        list.add(scala.Tuple2.apply(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }
    final scala.collection.Seq<Tuple2<K, V>> seq = scala.collection.JavaConverters.asScalaBufferConverter(list).asScala().toSeq();
    return (scala.collection.immutable.Map<K, V>) scala.collection.immutable.Map$.MODULE$.apply(seq);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since I couldn't make it with [Alexey's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64109626/2359227) answer, I'll add that in Scala 2.13 it can be done using:

```java
scala.collection.immutable.Map<Integer, String> scalaMap =
        scala.collection.immutable.Map.from(scala.jdk.CollectionConverters.MapHasAsScala(javaMap).asScala());
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me with java 1.8 and scala 2.12:

```java
public static <K, V> scala.collection.immutable.Map<K, V> toScalaImmutableMap(java.util.Map<K, V> jmap) {
    List<Tuple2<K, V>> tuples = jmap.entrySet()
      .stream()
      .map(e -> Tuple2.apply(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    Seq<Tuple2<K, V>> scalaSeq = JavaConverters.asScalaBuffer(tuples).toSeq();
    
    return (Map<K, V>) Map$.MODULE$.apply(scalaSeq);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Scala 2.13 you can use `CollectionConverters` to achieve that.

Having

```java
Map<String, String> javaMap = ...
```

First we convert it to mutable Scala map:

```
import scala.jdk.javaapi.CollectionConverters$;

var mutableScalaMap = CollectionConverters$.MODULE$.asScala(javaMap);
```

And then to immutable one:

```java
var scalaMap = scala.collection.immutable.Map$.MODULE$.from(mutableScalaMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide an additional API call that takes/provides a java.util.Map converted using [JavaConverters](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConverters%24.html) ?

```
class Example {
   import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
   def fromMap(m:Map[...]) = ...

   // generics etc. elided
   def fromJava(m:java.util.Map) = {
      fromMap(m.asScala.toMap)
   }
}
```

You may wish to extract the conversion and provide a decorator (especially as I note you're working to a Scala library). Note *dhg*'s comment re. immutability.

Comment: Yes. Hence my opening question - 'Can you provide an additional API call that takes/provides a java.util.Map'

Answer (score -1):

Simply use ***toMap*** (Scala 2.12)

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

// asScala creates mutable Scala Map
// toMap after asScala creates immutable Map

val scalaImmutableMap = javaMap.asScala.toMap
```

Comment: HI @TomerShetah I might be wrong ,but to convert Java to Scala collection , we should be writing the convertor in scala.

Comment: But the question asks for java code, which this is not. So it does not answer the question, regardless if you are right or wrong.