# Convert java hashmap to scala map

Tags: java, scala, type-conversion, typeconverter

In scala i have function like this:

```
def generateString(format: String, 
    parameters: Map[String, String] = Map()) {

    generate(format, parameters)    
}
```

And now, i want to call it form java

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("test1", "test2");
Generator.generateString("", params);
```

But i get error that cannot convert form java map to scala map.

So, how to solve this.

p.s. I am new to Scala.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903167/convert-java-util-hashmap-to-scala-collection-immutable-map-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Change your utility signature:

```
def generateString(format: String, 
    parameters: java.util.Map[String, String] = new java.util.HashMap()) {
```

Or use java-to-scala converter in Java code:

```
Generator.generateString("", scala.collection.JavaConversions.mapAsScalaMap(params));
```

Comment: For first solution i get error: - object java.util.HashMap is not a value