# How to convert a HashMap to a JavaPairRDD, in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am very new to Apache Spark. I am trying to create a `JavaPairRdd` from `HashMap`. I have a `HashMap` of type `<String,<Integer,Integer>>`
How can I convert it into a `JavaPairRdd`? I have pasted my code below:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer,String>> canlist =
    new HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer,String>>();

for (String key : entityKey)
{
    HashMap<Integer, String> clkey = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    int f=0;
    for (String val :mentionKey)
    {
        //do something
        simiscore = (longerLength - costs[m.length()]) / (double) longerLength;

        if (simiscore > 0.6) {
            clkey.put(v1,val);
            System.out.print(
                " The mention  " + val + " added to link entity  " + key);
            }
            f++;
            System.out.println("Scan Completed");
    }
    canlist.put(key,clkey);
    JavaPairRDD<String, HashMap<Integer, String>> rad;
    rad = context.parallelize(scala.collection.Seq(toScalaMap(canlist)));

}
public static <String,Object> Map<String,Object> toScalaMap(HashMap<String,Object> m) {
    return (Map<String,Object>) JavaConverters.mapAsScalaMapConverter(m).asScala().toMap(
            Predef.<Tuple2<String,Object>>conforms()
    );}
}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you provide an expected output. I see at least two possible options: `JavaPairRdd<String, HashMap<Integer, String>>` or  `JavaPairRdd<scala.Tuple2<String, Integer>, String>`

Comment: The expected output is of the form JavaPairRdd<String, HashMap<Integer, String>>

Comment: Using [`JavaConverters`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11903167/1560062) to convert to Scala Map, and then calling `toSeq` should work.

Comment: Is there any way to do it purely in Java?

Comment: As far as I know `parallelize` requires `scala.collection.Seq` as an argument.

Comment: Tried doing it this way. Gives me an error at scala.collection which says Qualifier must be an expression.  JavaPairRDD<String, HashMap<Integer, String>> rad;
            rad = context.parallelize(scala.collection.Seq(toScalaMap(canlist)));

        }
    public static <String,Object> Map<String,Object> toScalaMap(HashMap<String,Object> m) {
        return (Map<String,Object>) JavaConverters.mapAsScalaMapConverter(m).asScala().toMap(
                Predef.<Tuple2<String,Object>>conforms()
        );

Comment: It would be better if you post it as an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31628605/edit) to the question. Blocks of code in comments are rather hard to read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you convert the `HashMap` into a `List<scala.Tuple2<Integer, String>>`, then you can use [`JavaSparkContext.parallelizePairs`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html#parallelizePairs(java.util.List)).

Comment: Sorry I don't have a full example. I don't use Spark via Java. You're better off with Scala if you have that option!

Comment: This worked. Although I had to change the HashMap to List<Tuple2<Integer,String>>

Comment: Cool! I've added a note about this in the answer. I don't know how you do the actual conversion in Java. Perhaps you could add the code to the answer — sounds like it would be useful for future readers of this page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to convert java `HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer,String>>` to `List<Tuple2<String, HashMap<Integer,String>>>` and pass to parallelizePairs() method of JavaSparkContext.

```
import scala.Tuple2;

List<Tuple2<String, HashMap<Integer,String>>> list = new ArrayList<Tuple2<String, HashMap<Integer,String>>>();      
for(Map.Entry<String, HashMap<Integer,String>> entry : canlist.entrySet()){
    list1.add(new Tuple2<String, HashMap<Integer,String>>(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()));
  }

JavaPairRDD<String, HashMap<Integer, String>> javaPairRdd = jsc.parallelizePairs(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet of the generic method for conversion. Utilize `JavaSparkContext.parallelizePairs()` with the result of this method.

```
    //fromMapToListTuple2() generic method to convert Map<T1, T2> to List<Tuple2<T1, T2>>
    public static <T1, T2> List<Tuple2<T1, T2>> fromMapToListTuple2(Map<T1, T2> map)
    {
        //list of tuples
        List<Tuple2<T1, T2>> list = new ArrayList<Tuple2<T1, T2>>();

        //loop through all key-value pairs add them to the list
        for(T1 key : map.keySet())
        {
            //get the value
            T2 value = map.get(key);

            //Tuple2 is not like a traditional Java collection, but a single k-v pair;
            Tuple2<T1, T2> tuple2 = new Tuple2<T1, T2>(key, value);

            //populate the list with created tupple2
            list.add(tuple2);
        } // for

        return list;
    } // fromMapToListTuple2
```