# Converting a Java map into a Scala immutable map in Java code

Tags: scala

I have a Java class that needs to stay in Java for a variety of reasons. It is calling a method on a class implemented with a Scala trait and a Scala implementation that needs a Scala immutable map. Yes, I have seen how to use implicit and explicit code if I have the Java Map and I am doing the converting in Scala code, but I am trying to do the conversion from Java code and have seen nothing like that on Stack Overflow.

I am using Eclipse and the project has the Scala nature added to it. I tried importing scala.collection.JavaConverters, and Eclipse just gave me an error saying it couldn't find the class even though I can see the class when I open up the scala-library in the Scala Library container. I am using Scala 2.11.8

How can I write explicit code that converts the Java Map into the Scala Map in Java code?

Comment: I read through and tried to recreate that solution. Unfortunately I cannot import any of the Scala classes in my Java class, which I presume is something weird on my end. Sigh.

Comment: Sorry, but why can't you import any scala classes on your end? Even `scala.collection.immutable.Map`?

Comment: I wish I knew. But yeah, even scala.collection.immutable.Map will not import.

Comment: I suppose this is a problem with Eclipse. Try to reimport the project and see if it works.

Comment: No that is not a very good idea, using Scala code from Java is just horrible... the Scala compiler generates weird names that are not human-readable. Using Java from Scala is much easier because the Java compiler is way simpler and the naming rules of methods and classes much more restrictive. Simply use `JavaConversions`.

Comment: I agree, using Scala from Java is horrible. But it will sometimes be necessary and I ran into that time, which was fortunately just a small usage. But now that I see what interoperate is like, I am beginning to wonder if doing future work in Scala is a good idea if I want people to have a choice of using Java. Anyway, I got Eclipse sorted out. It was odd, containers in the .classpath file when flipped made it work.

Comment: BTW, my problem was solved by following a few threads. I apologize that a solution was out there, I tried searching and never found those discussions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903167/convert-java-util-hashmap-to-scala-collection-immutable-map-in-java/11903737#11903737 solves the problem in the more "modern" way. Which just misses a few $s.

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply use ***toMap***.

Something Like :

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

// asScala creates mutable Scala Map
// toMap after asScala creates immutable Map
val scalaImmutableMap = javaMap.asScala.toMap
```

Comment: because Java map does not have the "asScala".

Comment: @AminHeydariAlashti that's the reason import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
 was used.