# Java Dataset using Scala class

Tags: java, spring-boot, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to use Spark SQL in the spring boot application. We would want to create the dataset from the list of objects (Employee). The Employee is a Scala case class that is defined by another team and we were able to define the list of objects in our project

But when we were trying to create a dataset from that list, we are getting an empty dataset without any values.

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
employees.add(new Employee(1,"Tom",25));
Dataset<Row> employeeDF = spark.createDataFrame(employees,Employee.class);
```

The employeeDF is coming out to be empty, so not sure if we are doing it correctly or missing anything.

Is it possible to create a Dataset from the list of objects that refer to the Scala case class?

I tried everywhere to look for the issue and I was not able to find it. If its a duplicate please let me know.

Thanks for your reply Harminder

Comment: How do you "see" that the DF is empty?

Comment: check Andrey Tyukin answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48619101/how-to-bridge-scala-case-classes-and-collections-to-java

Comment: @GaëlJ When I ran `employeeDF.show()`, it was showing me an empty record.

Comment: @shalnarkftw Thank you but looks like we would have to rewrite those classes in Java. Cannot do changes on Scala side as it is defined by other team and whatever we can we have to do in our Java code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference the output of employeeDF.show() is:

```
++
||
++
||
++
```

This is due to:

```scala
Dataset<Row> employeeDF = spark.createDataFrame(employees,Employee.class);
```

expecting a bean class, which Employee probably isn't, you need an Encoder to handle Scala Products (case class or tuple), which needs the Scala compiler in order to generate a TypeTag.  Ask your Scala team to add this object to their code (based on [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38591695/1028537)):

```scala
object TypeUtils {

  import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}

  import scala.reflect.api.Universe

  import scala.reflect.ClassTag
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  def typeTag[T](clazz: Class[T]): TypeTag[T] = {
    val classTag = ClassTag[T](clazz)

    val m = runtimeMirror(clazz.getClassLoader)
    val tpe = m.classSymbol(clazz).toType
    val typeCreator = new scala.reflect.api.TypeCreator {
      def apply[U <: Universe with Singleton](m1: scala.reflect.api.Mirror[U]): U # Type =
        if (m1 != m) throw new RuntimeException("wrong mirror") else tpe.asInstanceOf[U#Type]
    }
    val typeTag = TypeTag[T](m, typeCreator)
    typeTag
  }

  def productEncoderFor[T <: Product](clazz: Class[T]): Encoder[T] =
    Encoders.product[T](typeTag(clazz))
}
```

, then you can write:

```scala
Dataset<Employee> employeeDF = spark.createDataset(employees, TypeUtils.productEncoderFor(Employee.class));
employeeDF.show();
```

yielding:

```
+---+----+---+
| id|name|age|
+---+----+---+
|  1| Tom| 25|
+---+----+---+
```

The productEncoderFor function will work for any such case class / tuple.  If you really need a Dataset<Row> then just call .toDF() after creating the dataset.