# How to convert Java Map of Lists to Scala Map of Lists

Tags: java, scala

I have a Java Map of lists,

```
Map<String, List<String>> stringToListOfStrings = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        stringToListOfStrings.put("key1", Arrays.asList("k1v1", "k1v2"));
        stringToListOfStrings.put("key2", Arrays.asList("k2v1", "k2v2"));
        stringToListOfStrings.put("key3", Arrays.asList("k3v1", "k3v2"));
```

I want to convert this to Scala Map of lists

```
Map[String,List[String]]
```

Would like to know the conversion on both in `Java` and `Scala`.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11903737/4550466) but didn't get the expected output

and on Scala side,

```
def convertJavaToScala(stringString: java.util.HashMap[String, java.util.List[String]]) {
    val scalaMap = stringString.asScala
    scalaMap.get("key1")
    scalaMap.get("key1").foreach(println)
  }
```

but the **result was a comma separated string of values**.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the way to do it:

```scala
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

  def convertJavaToScala(stringString: java.util.HashMap[String, java.util.List[String]]): Map[String,List[String]] = {
    val scalaMap: Map[String, java.util.List[String]] = stringString.asScala.toMap
    scalaMap.mapValues(_.asScala.toList)
  }
```

And when you run:

```scala
import java.util.Arrays

  val stringToListOfStrings = new java.util.HashMap[String, java.util.List[String]]()
  stringToListOfStrings.put("key1", Arrays.asList("k1v1", "k1v2"))
  stringToListOfStrings.put("key2", Arrays.asList("k2v1", "k2v2"))
  stringToListOfStrings.put("key3", Arrays.asList("k3v1", "k3v2"))

convertJavaToScala(stringToListOfStrings)
// Displays
// Map(key1 -> List(k1v1, k1v2), key2 -> List(k2v1, k2v2), key3 -> List(k3v1, k3v2))
```

Basically, you have to add `.toMap` / `.toList` after `.asScala` because `Map` and `List` are immutable in Scala, unlike Java.

Comment: I did val scalaMapConverted: Map[String, List[String]] = scalaMap.mapValues(_.asScala.toList) but Im getting Unit required Map[String,List[String]]

Comment: I am not sure in which context you are running this, but if that's the last statement of your method, it is indeed `Unit`, you either need to return `scalaMap` or not assigning `scalaMap.mapValues(_.asScala.toList)` to a variable

Answer (score 2):

This is an efficient way of doing the conversion:

```
def convertJavaToScala(ss: java.util.HashMap[String, java.util.List[String]]): Map[String, List[String]] =
  ss.asScala.map{ case (k, v) => k -> v.asScala.toList }(collection.breakOut)
```

Using `map` rather than `mapValues` avoids repeatedly evaluating the conversion code when elements of the `Map` are accessed. Using `collection.breakOut` means that an `immutable.Map` will be created directly from the `map` call so there is no need to convert to `immutable.Map` before the `map` call.