# how to convert java map to scala map using scala.collection.JavaConverters

Tags: java, scala

I try to convert java map to scala map in java static function.

```
OS: windows 11 
jdk: 17
spark : spark-3.4.1-bin-hadoop3
ide : visual studio code
```

Below codes are the converting function.

```
import scala.Predef;
import scala.Tuple2;
import scala.collection.JavaConverters;

private static <A,B> scala.collection.immutable.Map<A, B> toScalaMap(java.util.Map<A, B> m) {
     return JavaConverters.mapAsScalaMapConverter(m).asScala().toMap(Predef.<Tuple2<A,B>>$conforms());
}
```

But the toMap function throws the exception.

```
The method toMap($less$colon$less<Tuple2<A,B>,Tuple2<K$,V$>>) in the type IterableOnceOps<Tuple2<A,B>,Iterable,Map<A,B>> is not applicable for the arguments (Function1<Tuple2<A,B>,Tuple2<A,B>>)
```

It seems that the parameters of toMap function are not correct. But I am a newbie of scala and I have no idea how to correct the toMap function parameters. Kindly inform me what the correct parameters have to be.

**== Updated Part**

Kindly check my codes. Below codes throw Errors.

```
private static <A,B> scala.collection.immutable.Map<A, B> toScalaMap(java.util.Map<A, B> m) {
        List<Tuple2<A,B>> javaTuples = m.entrySet().stream()
                .map(x -> Tuple2.apply(x.getKey(), x.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
        scala.collection.Map<A,B> scalaMap = scala.collection.Map$.MODULE$.apply(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(javaTuples).toSeq());
        return scalaMap;
    }
```

The errors are

```
The method asScalaBuffer(List<Tuple2<A,B>>) is undefined for the type JavaConversions.
```

**== Updated Part 2**

These are my java codes.

```
private static <A,B> scala.collection.immutable.Map<A, B> toScalaMap(Map<A, B> m) {
    return JavaConverters.mapAsScalaMapConverter(m).asScala().toMap(Predef.$conforms());
}

SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName(appName).getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("kafka")
            .options(kafkaParams)
            .load()
            .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as column").filter(not(col("column").startsWith("date")));

Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
            
Dataset<Row> dfs = df.select(from_csv(col("column"), StoredColumnPojo.getStructType(), toScalaMap(options))
            .as("entityStoredPojo"))
            .selectExpr("entityStoredPojo.date", "entityStoredPojo.value", "entityStoredPojo.id", 
                        "entityStoredPojo.title", "entityStoredPojo.state", "entityStoredPojo.frequency_short", 
                        "entityStoredPojo.units_short", "entityStoredPojo.seasonal_adjustment_short").toDF();
```

As you see, `toScalaMap(options)` method is parameter function to execute spark dataframe api. The above codes works successfully with spark-core_2.12, version 3.2.1. But I upgrade the spark-core_2.13 and the toScalaMap function throws the exception. I think the error is the matter of version problem, but I have no idea why.

Comment: Do you have an option to write a helper in Scala? It would be much easier if you could create an `object` or `class` with some helpers translating from-Scala-to-Java in Scala but exposing Java API, that you would just call from Java.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Kindly check my 'updated part 2'. and if you have any question, pls do not hesitate giving me reply.

Comment: Sweet Jesus, Spark was never intended to be used from Java - it is supposed to be used from Scala, Python or R. You're gonna have to rewrite this code on a regular basic because some things were designed to be "source-compatible" not "binary compatible": code would look the same in Scala 2.12 and 2.13 (or 3) while the bytecode would look completely different! Scala was intended to be superset of Java and trying to use it the other way round is like trying to using C++ from C while manually mangling functions' names and reverse engineering vtables. It doesn't scale at all.

Answer (score 0):

@Joseph Hwang I think you need to deal with Tuples to do this conversion by using **asScalaBuffer**. Please try with the below approach to get the Scala Map.

```
    private static <A,B> scala.collection.immutable.Map<A, B> toScalaMap(java.util.Map<A, B> m) {
      List<Tuple2<A,B>> javaTuples = javaMap.entrySet().stream()
                .map(x -> Tuple2.apply(x.getKey(), x.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
      scala.collection.Map scalaMap = scala.collection.Map$.MODULE$.apply(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(javaTuples).toSeq());
      return scalaMap;
}
```

For further details refere to this post as well.

[Convert java.util.HashMap to scala.collection.immutable.Map in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903167/convert-java-util-hashmap-to-scala-collection-immutable-map-in-java/45373345#45373345)

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply. But the error is thrown from the codes. Kindly check my Updated Part. I am afraid some APIs are deprecated.